# Angular не обновляет view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

После принятия данных с сервера, *Angular* не обновляет данные, попытался использовать *$apply*, но возникла новая проблема:

> Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress

Вот примеры кода:

```
function loadData() {
    $http.post('/data').success(function (data) {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.tableData = data;
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ангуляр вызывает `$apply` автоматически при вызове функций из `$http`, поэтому при вызове `$apply` внутри вручную получается данная ошибка.

Comment: как тогда быть? View не обновляется

Comment: @АлександрБондаренко, все зависит от вашего кода и разметки, добавьте в вопрос [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Была такая проблема, удалось решить таким способом:

```js
$http({
  "method": "POST",
  "url": "/Home/Save",
  data: {
    name: $scope.name
  }
}).success(function (data) {
  if (data.success === true) {
    $scope.refreshArray().then(function refreshArrayComplete() { 
      if (!$scope.$$phase) {
        $scope.$apply();
      }
    });
  }
}).error(function (err) {
  $scope.showError(err.data);
});
```